# Nice URLs in meidawiki and nginx gives error: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, mediawiki

so I set up Mediawiki on a server and it worked nice. Now I wanted to change the virtual server config of nginx so I have nice urls. I followed this doc: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Nginx

Here are my settings:

Working conf: https://paste.ngx.cc/ab

Not working conf (nice urls):
Virtual Server: https://paste.ngx.cc/1436
LocalSettings.php has added:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/mediawiki";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

The wiki is installed at /var/www/my-site.com/mediawiki

The error is:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server:
>   my-site.ch, request: "GET /wiki/Main_page HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "www.my-site.com"

Entry from access log:

> "GET
>   /load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=ext.uls.webfonts.fonts%2Crepository%7Cjquery.webfonts&skin=timeless&version=1ejfn7l
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 19908 "http://www.my-site.ch/index.php?title=Main_Page"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"

Any idea what exactly is going on?